# Adding an accordion group to a Twitter Bootstrap accordion dynamically doesn't get recognized by the accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my current project, I have a number of tabs, each displaying a different accordion containing requests made via the web by potential customers.  Each tab represents a workflow stage.  In the first tab I have an accordion where once a request (accordion group) gets "claimed" by the user, it is removed from it's current accordion and appended to the accordion in the next tab.  This functionality works fine.  The issue I'm having is the new parent accordion doesn't seem to recognize that a new accordion group was added, so I'm able to expand that accordion group independent of the others in the accordion.  It collapses if I expand one of the others, but if I expand it back, the others that are already expanded don't collapse like they should.  This problem goes away upon refreshing the page, but I'm trying to avoid that.

All the accordion groups have data-parent set correctly.  I'm even changing the value of data-parent on the accordion group I'm moving, so that it's also correct.

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT adding code which is called when user claims a request**

```
define(['jquery', 'util', 'text!../templates/alert.html!strip', 'models/Claimer', 'models/RateQuote'], function($, util, tAlert) {
  return {
    /**
     * Claim an unclaimed request.
     *
     * @param row The request row.
     * @param id The request ID.
     * @param name The user's name who is claiming the request.
     * @param newActions Array of actions to replace the existing actions menu.
     */
    claim: function(row, id, name, newActions) {
      var claimer = new Claimer(name);

      $.ajax({
        url: '/webrequests/request/claimRequest/' + id,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(claimer),
        success: function(data) {
          if($(row).siblings().length == 0)
            util.noData(row.parent('.accordion'));

          $(row).children('.accordion-heading').children('.accordion-toggle').attr('data-parent', '#claimed-by-me-accordion');

          var claimedByMeAccordion = $('#claimed-by-me-accordion');
          $(claimedByMeAccordion).children('.no-data').remove();

          $(row).appendTo(claimedByMeAccordion);

          $('.createDate', row).html('No response sent').removeClass('createDate').addClass('respondDate');
          $('.actions', row).children().remove();
          $('.actions', row).append(newActions);
        }
      });
    },
```

Comment: Could we see any code you have tried?

Comment: I've just added the code that gets called when a user claims a request.  This function will remove the accordion group from the current accordion and move it to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap will automatically convert everything in the DOM at load time to the appropriate widget types, but it will not listen to new elements added to the DOM. For this, you'll need to manually specify the new row is collapsible after you add it. Fortunately, this should be pretty simple. Try appending .collapse() to the appendTo as shown:

```
$(row).appendTo(claimedByMeAccordion).collapse();
```

See also the docs: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: I just tried that.  However in the target accordion, all I saw where I expected the new row to be was a line.  Seems it added "in" and "collapse" classes directly to the .accordion-group if I look at the DOM in Chrome.  I tried calling collapse() on the .accordion-body, but that didn't do anything.